# I want to have an element overhang into the element above it

Tags: css, styling

I'm having trouble figuring this out, ove tried to have the element in an absolute position and had it where i want it but it only worked for a certain screen size. the code looks like this.

```
aside#form{
   float: right;
   margin-right: 5%;
   width: 28%;
   line-height: 2em;
   background: #4a455c;
   color: #fff;
   padding: 0 50px;
}
```

I'm using css and cant seem to figure out how to overhang the top section into the element above it.

[Image source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04blf.png)

HTML is as follows

```
<aside id="form">
<h3>Join our mailing list</h3>
  <input type="email" placeholder="Your email address">
    <button type="button" class="button-3">Subscribe</button>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sed adipisicing elit, sed eiusmod do tempor.</p>
        <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f fa-2x"></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter fa-2x"></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram fa-2x"></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-github fa-2x"></i></a>
```

Comment: Can you share your HTML as well?

Comment: You want one element above the other?

Comment: Please share your HTML and a screenshot of what the problem is

Comment: html has been included sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my approach, this will be my recommendation. in your footer add style `position:relative;` my example below.

```
<div class="footer" style="position: relative;">
  <form class="overhang-div" style="position: absolute; right:0; top: -20px;"></form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean simply to have the background encroach onto an element above then try using `style="margin-top: -2em;"` changing the -2 in relation to how much you want it to overlap. If you want it to slide completely over the above element in scrolling then make `style="position: fixed; z-index: 1;"`